# Need help in finding flags in secret files

Tags: ctf

Need help in identifying or decrypting strings to find flags in capture the flag competitions. Please provide any guides or help.

Comment: question edited since it is not a duplicate of old one.

Comment: It’s not a duplicate but it still needs to be closed as we don’t answer questions about breaking specific ciphers.

Comment: @CamfySura: to be of some more help: it is deeply nested. The first layer is a typical encoding of binary data, the second layer can be found by using the UNIX file command, for the next layer take a  deeper look (hex, characters) into what decoding the second layer gave you.

Comment: @CamfySura: To cite myself: *"The first layer is a typical encoding of binary data, the second layer can be found by using the UNIX file command"*. You've obviously missed the first step, i.e. decoding it into binary data. Call `file` only on the decoded result.

Comment: @CamfySura this new edit is far too broad to be answerable